# Creating rows from other tables when creating an associative table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables `Strike`, `Fire` and `StrikeFire` (associative table). I am trying to store only strikes that cause data if they have the same date, latitude and longitude.

Here is how I am trying to populate the associative table with existing id records. I am stuck after the FROM condition

```
INSERT INTO StrikeFire SELECT StrikeID, FireID FROM
```

Below are the tables and data

```
CREATE TABLE Strike (StrikeID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                     StrikeDate date NOT NULL,
                     StrikeTime time NOT NULL,
                     StrikeLatitude numeric(4, 2) NOT NULL,
                     StrikeLongitude numeric(5, 2) NOT NULL,
                     StrikeIntensity int NOT NULL,
                     CONSTRAINT PK_Strike
                         PRIMARY KEY (StrikeID));

CREATE TABLE Fire (FireID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                   FireDate date NOT NULL,
                   FireLatitude numeric(4, 2) NOT NULL,
                   FireLongitude numeric(5, 2) NOT NULL,
                   FireArea numeric(6, 2) NOT NULL,
                   CONSTRAINT PK_Fire
                       PRIMARY KEY (FireID));

CREATE TABLE StrikeFire (StrikeID int NOT NULL,
                         FireID int NOT NULL,
                         CONSTRAINT PK_StrikeFire
                             PRIMARY KEY (
                             StrikeID,
                             FireID),
                         CONSTRAINT FK_Strike
                             FOREIGN KEY (StrikeID)
                             REFERENCES Strike (StrikeID),
                         CONSTRAINT FK_Fire
                             FOREIGN KEY (FireID)
                             REFERENCES Fire (FireID));
```

Here is dummy insert data

```
INSERT INTO Strike (StrikeDate,
                    StrikeTime,
                    StrikeLatitude,
                    StrikeLongitude,
                    StrikeIntensity)
VALUES ('05-05-2006', '02:02', 41.34, -122.45, 6235),
       ('05-05-2006', '02:09', 40.47, -120.47, 16235),
       ('05-05-2006', '03:32', 42.14, -122.98, 7779),
       ('05-05-2006', '04:34', 38.32, -122.17, 4645),
       ('05-05-2006', '05:02', 39.04, -121.22, 8989);

INSERT INTO Fire (FireDate,
                  FireLatitude,
                  FireLongitude,
                  FireArea)
VALUES ('05-05-2006', 32.34, -122.45, 123.90),
       ('05-05-2006', 37.19, -121.66, 627.09),
       ('05-05-2006', 40.47, -120.47, 45.00),
       ('05-05-2006', 42.14, -122.98, 1774.90),
       ('05-05-2006', 37.21, -120.47, 2034.80),
       ('05-05-2006', 42.04, -126.22, 49.62);
```

Comment: Aehm, what's the point in editing the original question beyond recognition?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO StrikeFire 
SELECT StrikeID, FireID 
FROM Fire F
Join Strike S
on F.FireDate = S.StrikeDate
and F.FireLatitude = S.StrikeLatitude
and F.FireLongitude = S.StrikeLongitude
```

Answer (score 1):

Well done on a very comprehensive question!

All you need to do here is use a `JOIN` with several expression in the `ON` clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.StrikeFire (StrikeID,
                            FireID)
SELECT S.StrikeID, F.FireID
FROM dbo.Strike S
     JOIN dbo.Fire F ON S.StrikeDate = F.FireDate
                    AND S.StrikeLatitude = F.FireLatitude
                    AND S.StrikeLongitude = F.FireLongitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `INNER JOIN` should work :

```
INSERT INTO StrikeFire (StrikeID, FireID)
   SELECT f.StrikeID, s.FireID 
   FROM Fire F INNER JOIN 
        Strike S
        ON F.FireDate = S.StrikeDate AND 
           F.FireLatitude = S.StrikeLatitude AND 
           F.FireLongitude = S.StrikeLongitude;
```